# Anaconda won't update: "No default base environment" error

Tags: python, macos, anaconda, conda, macos-catalina

### Issue

I've been trying to update my Anaconda installation, but whether I run the updater from the GUI or the Terminal via `conda update conda`, I receive the error: `"NoBaseEnvironmentError: This conda installation has no default base environment."`

I don't understand what is going on here. I have successfully run Python 2 and 3 scripts on this computer. Every tutorial I've found assumes a base environment is created by default. When I run `conda info --envs` I see an active environment named "base":

```
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  /Users/MYUSERNAME/anaconda3
ipykernel_py2            /Users/MYUSERNAME/anaconda3/envs/ipykernel_py2
                         /Users/MYUSERNAME/opt/anaconda3
```

I'm not well-versed in Python or the command line, so I'd appreciate any help in solving this. I imagine all I need to do is set the base environment, but after much Googling I cannot figure out how to do so. All I want to do is update Anaconda.

### Things I've Tried

`conda activate` prior to running update command

`conda activate base` prior to running update command

`sudo conda update conda`

`conda update -p /Users/MYUSERNAME/anaconda3 conda`

All have resulted in the same error.

### System Details

I'm running `MacOS Catalina 10.15.5`, `Conda version 4.7.10`

`conda info` output:

```
 active environment : base
    active env location : /Users/MYUSERNAME/anaconda3
            shell level : 1
       user config file : /Users/MYUSERNAME/.condarc
 populated config files : /Users/MYUSERNAME/.condarc
          conda version : 4.7.10
    conda-build version : 3.18.8
         python version : 3.7.3.final.0
       virtual packages : 
       base environment : /Users/MYUSERNAME/anaconda3  (read only)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : /Users/MYUSERNAME/anaconda3/pkgs
                          /Users/MYUSERNAME/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /Users/MYUSERNAME/.conda/envs
                          /Users/MYUSERNAME/anaconda3/envs
               platform : osx-64
             user-agent : conda/4.7.10 requests/2.22.0 CPython/3.7.3 Darwin/19.5.0 OSX/10.15.5
                UID:GID : 501:20
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

`conda config --show-sources` output:

```
==> /Users/MYUSERNAME/.condarc <==
ssl_verify: True
channels:
  - defaults
```

Comment: Did you try the solution here: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8930

Comment: It looks to me like Anaconda was installed twice, once in `/Users/shardsofblue/anaconda3` and one in `/Users/shardsofblue/opt/anaconda3`. Likely need to remove the latter, but we need more info first. Could you add the full output of `conda info` to the question?

Comment: @IgorRivin That page doesn't really have a solution, though I did attempt to use "activate base".

Comment: @merv I have added the ```conda info``` output.

Comment: What's up with `/Users/MYUSERNAME/anaconda3  (read only)`? Could you show the output of `ls -ld /Users/MYUSERNAME/anaconda3`? I'm wondering what the permissions are that are blocking you from writing to it.

Comment: @merv ```drwxr-xr-x  29 MYUSERNAME  staff  928 Jun 23 13:30 /Users/MYUSERNAME/anaconda3``` This is my personal computer so I have no idea why I would have anything less than full permissions.

Comment: If you installed anaconda as root, then you have to update it as root too.

Comment: The permissions look fine on that folder please check the subdirectories that they also have something similar. What does `which -a conda` show?

Comment: @merv 
```/Users/MYUSERNAME/anaconda3/bin/conda
/Users/MYUSERNAME/anaconda3/condabin/conda```

Comment: All subdirectories have the same permissions, but there is a file I don't recognize called ```org.freedesktop.dbus-session.plist``` in that directory with ```-rw-rw-r--``` permissions.

Comment: Everything looks fine (assuming you having **base** activated) - including the `plist` file. I'm not sure what else could be the issue. Might need to reinstall. If you go that route, make sure to [fully clean up this installation first](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall/).

Comment: Well shoot, I was hoping to avoid the "nuke it from orbit" option. Thanks very much for your help, though; really appreciate your taking the time!

Comment: If you haven't nuked it yet, I just searched the codebase and there is only [one place that raised this error](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/1f79e64403385407cda56830c3675c47d53a3942/conda/cli/install.py#L142). It looks like you could play around with `conda update -p /Users/MYUSERNAME/anaconda3 conda`.

Comment: @merv I decided to put off deleting/reinstalling it until tomorrow, so I just ran that line, but still got the same error. Are there other ways to "play around" with it that you had in mind? I'm afraid the codebase is way over my head.

Comment: @RoxanneReady the code shows it raises the error when the `conda update conda` is attempted to be run on a non-base env. The definition of base could come through `.condarc` or an environment variable. I suspect you may be able to get the command to work by redefining that variable to match the **base** directory.

Comment: What does `echo $CONDA_PREFIX` say? It should be `/Users/MYUSERNAME/anaconda3`. If not, you might try `CONDA_PREFIX=/Users/MYUSERNAME/anaconda3 conda update -p /Users/MYUSERNAME/anaconda3 conda`.

Answer (score 5):

See if there is a file called `history` in `~/anaconda3/conda-meta/`.
If not, create it by writing `touch ~/anaconda3/conda-meta/history`.

@igor-rivin has already pointed in the direction of this solution in his comment, the post in question is [here](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8930#issuecomment-653465668)

Comment: I had that issue, I'm using `miniconda2`, the directory found at: `/miniconda2/conda-meta`, and there were no `history` file, so I copied one in to that directory. Now the command `conda update --name base conda` works for me.

Comment: That does nothing at all for me as I just did "dnf install conda"

Answer (score 3):

You need to restart your shell after installing it.

Comment: This worked for me in the end

Comment: The warning messages are explicit now.

Answer (score 2):

I never found the solution to this, but resolved the issue by doing a full clean uninstall of Anaconda using the free trial for App Cleaner Uninstaller. (I first followed uninstall instructions from two different places and still missed a number of key files.)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue a few months ago. I solved the issue by finding the _conda.exe file in the Anaconda3 directory. Today, I was having issues with finding packages and using pip/conda. I ended up uninstalling anaconda and manually deleting all related files.

All of this to say, make sure you're operating in the 'Anaconda Prompt' application. After running the application, the base environment will be automatically activated.
Note that you will have to run the application as an administrator if you downloaded conda to be used by any user on the PC. If you have installed it this way, it will be located in C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3. I suggest adding this to your environment variables to find it easily next time you go in to manage your packages.

Comment: I also discovered that if you're looking to install a package using conda, but the conda version is severely outdated (Pygame, for example), then you'll want to run the Anaconda Prompt application and use the already installed pip package. Anaconda includes pip as a package by default as of 9/15/2022

Answer (score -4):

You need activate conda enviroment

```
conda activate base
```

Comment: does nothing when this problem comes up